# Trying to move turtle object to random location

Tags: python, random, methods, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to switch up this method to allow the fish to try up to 4  random locations for its next move.  I've tried a few cracks at it, but I haven't figured out a good way yet.

```
def tryToMove(self):
        offsetList = [(-1, 1), (0, 1), (1, 1),
                  (-1, 0)        , (1, 0),
                  (-1, -1), (0, -1), (1, -1)]
        randomOffsetIndex = random.randrange(len(offsetList))
        randomOffset = offsetList[randomOffsetIndex]
        nextx = self.xpos + randomOffset[0]
        nexty = self.ypos + randomOffset[1]
        while not(0 <= nextx < self.world.getMaxX() and 0 <= nexty < self.world.getMaxY()):
            randomOffsetIndex = random.randrange(len(offsetList))
            randomOffset = offsetList[randomOffsetIndex]
            nextx = self.xpos + randomOffset[0]
            nexty = self.ypos + randomOffset[1]

        if self.world.emptyLocation(nextx, nexty):
            self.move(nextx, nexty)
```

Comment: BTW `randomOffset = random.choice(offsetList)`

Comment: What is the problem ? Do you get error message ? Show it in question? Or create minimal working example so we could run it and see problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually don't comment on code that I can't run but I'll take a crack at this.  Below is how I might design this method.

```
offsetList = [(-1, 1), (0, 1), (1, 1), (-1, 0), (1, 0), (-1, -1), (0, -1), (1, -1)]

def tryToMove(self):

    maxX = self.world.getMaxX()
    maxY = self.world.getMaxY()

    possibleOffsets = offsetList[:]  # make a copy we can change locally

    while possibleOffsets:
        possibleOffset = random.choice(possibleOffsets)  # ala @furas

        nextx = self.xpos + possibleOffset[0]
        nexty = self.ypos + possibleOffset[1]

        if (0 <= nextx < maxX() and 0 <= nexty < maxY()) and self.world.emptyLocation(nextx, nexty):
            self.move(nextx, nexty)
            return True  # valid move possible and made

        possibleOffsets.remove(possibleOffset)  # remove invalid choice

    return False  # no valid move possible for various reasons
```

I don't know what you mean by:

> try up to 4 random locations for its next move

since there are up to 8 possibilities, but if you really want to limit it, then here's an alternate approach that finds all `possibleOffsets` which you can trim as needed:

```
offsetList = [(-1, 1), (0, 1), (1, 1), (-1, 0), (1, 0), (-1, -1), (0, -1), (1, -1)]

def tryToMove(self):

    maxX = self.world.getMaxX()
    maxY = self.world.getMaxY()

    possibleOffsets = []

    for possibleOffset in offsetList:
        nextx = self.xpos + possibleOffset[0]
        nexty = self.ypos + possibleOffset[1]

        if 0 <= nextx < maxX and 0 <= nexty < maxY and self.world.emptyLocation(nextx, nexty):
            possibleOffsets.append(possibleOffset)

    if possibleOffsets:
        offsetX, offsetY = random.choice(possibleOffsets)  # ala @furas
        nextx = self.xpos + offsetX
        nexty = self.ypos + offsetY

        self.move(nextx, nexty)
        return True  # valid move possible and made

    return False  # no valid move possible for various reasons
```